# ASP.NET Access Denied when trying to run one process but not another?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

So I have a few tasks that need to happen on the server when the client performs a task, basically to take the data they uploaded and archive it off...doing nothing but calling Robocopy via a Process.start() call.  This is what does not work when deployed, it DOES work on my development machine with VS2012, but not when deployed, so i am sure it has to do with permissions of the ASP account but no matter what permissions i give it or other accounts i get the same error.  Ive tried a ton of things ive read on the net with no success, trying to start the process as a set user, turning on "Allow service to interact with desktop" for the IIS Admin Service...nothing seems to work and its driving me nuts because the other process on another page just ran without any of this permission problems...Please help!

It should be noted i did give my NETWORK SERVICE account full permission on D:\Websites\Ethreport

I constantly get the following error on my servers log

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          1/6/2014 9:27:03 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      NPPVSUBMITTAL.amr.corp.com
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 1/6/2014 9:27:03 AM 
Event time (UTC): 1/6/2014 5:27:03 PM 
Event ID: 2ea3f9b6d24f4cda8bbc7159df2e45bd 
Event sequence: 20 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-130335028137169135 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: D:\WebSites\EthReport\ 
Machine name: NPPVSUBMITTAL 

Process information: 
Process ID: 4004 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
Exception type: Win32Exception 
Exception message: Access is denied
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at PAENPPVSubmittal.Admin_SubmissionDetails.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean      includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://ethreport.com/Admin_SubmissionDetails.aspx?SubmissionID=2 
Request path: /Admin_SubmissionDetails.aspx 
User host address: x.x.x.x 
User: AMR\mydomainlogin
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: Negotiate 
Thread account name: AMR\sys_account

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 7 
Thread account name: AMR\sys_account 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at PAENPPVSubmittal.Admin_SubmissionDetails.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details:
```

I should also note that i have another Process.start() function on another page that runs an application and I had none of these issues with permissions.  I have ensured that both that process's folder and this folder have the same permissions for each user, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This may be down to the double hop issue.